# No such entity with customerId = ","1"

Tags: customer-account, magento2.3.4, register, customer-registration

I get this error when trying to register an account : "No such entity with customerId = ","1"

Please help to resolve this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please apply this patch in 2.3.2 https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/magento/magento2/pull/25307.diff

Or upgrade to 2.3.4

Source: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/25307